# SQL Server: Count integers with high precision

Tags: count, sql-server-2012, long-integer

I'm struggling with a query in SQL Server. I have the following columns:

Member Number; Dependant Number; Provider Number; Service Date

I concatenate the above to create a unique ID, see extract below:

---

```
MbrNo     DepNo  PracticeNo ServiceDt                UniqueProviderConsults
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   1    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077141820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-02 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041820
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-07 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041825
100000838   1    243264     2014-07-09 00:00:00.000  243264100000838141827
100000838   5    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100000838541832
100000838   3    243264     2014-07-17 00:00:00.000  243264100000838341835
100000838   0    243264     2014-07-17 00:00:00.000  243264100000838041835
100000838   5    243264     2014-07-18 00:00:00.000  243264100000838541836
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001077   0    243264     2014-07-14 00:00:00.000  243264100001077041832
100001480   1    243264     2014-07-17 00:00:00.000  243264100001480141835
```

---

My Unique ID is a numeric(30) data type. I then want to count the how many times the Unique ID appears. Using count_big, I do not get any overflow warnings but it still does not give me the right count. I think it is because a precision of 30 is too high so it cuts it off when counting. Is there another alternative?Unfortunately the components above are the minimum number of components to define the Unique ID. I have tried taking the log of my unique ID but the count is also  incorrect.

Can someone please help:)

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE [Claims Edited] ADD [UniqueProviderConsults] NUMERIC(30)
GO
UPDATE [Claims Edited] SET [UniqueProviderConsults] = CONCAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,0),ProviderNo),CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,0),MbrNo),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DepNo),CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,0),ServiceDt))
GO

Select PracticeNo,

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-06-30' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Jun-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-07-31' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Jul-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-08-31' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Aug-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-09-30' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Sep-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-10-31' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Oct-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-11-30' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Nov-14 Consults],

count_big(DISTINCT case when [ServiceMth]='2014-12-31' THEN [UniqueProviderConsults] else 0 end) as [Dec-14 Consults],

Into [EM Consultation Count temp]
from [EM Claims Edited]
Group by PracticeNo
```

Using the data from the extract above

**Provider Number 243264**
For the month of June 2014, there are no lines yet my code counts 1.
For the month of July 2014, there are 10 unique IDs, yet my code counts 11.

Comment: Why not use some character type for unique id? It is not number anyway.

Comment: Can we see your code, please?

Comment: Hi Arvo, using varchar gives me an overflow error

Comment: Please take the time to format your code. In this case, all you need to do is highlight the code and press the "code" button in the formatting toolbar. Can you give a simple example of where your results are wrong and what you to expect them to be? (Also, `count_big` has nothing to do with the size of the actual values being counted; it's only used where you might count so many *rows* that you'll overflow an integer. Do you really have that many rows?)

Comment: I have 20285 rows. Sorry I am new at this...I will try format the code:)

Comment: In that case, there's no need for `COUNT_BIG`. Just `COUNT` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have changed it to count but still getting incorrect counts. I edited my question above to incorporate what you asked for

Comment: This may just meant that `COUNT` doesn't do what you think it does. For example, run this standalone query: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 0)` and you'll find the result is 1, because there's one row in your result set. (This is nothing to do with the size of your integers, or precision. It's just how `COUNT` works...)

Comment: (As a quick fix with your existing code, what happens if you use `...else CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC)...` instead of `...else 0...`? `NULL`s don't get `COUNT`ed...) But you may want to take a step back, do grouping by month as well as practice and look into `PIVOT` for turning result rows into columns afterwards.